# How to set up linear programming problem for maximizing score of various combinations?

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, linear-programming, discrete-optimization

I have a sample data set that looks like this:

```
  x y w
1 1 5 1
2 1 6 2
3 1 7 3
4 2 8 4
5 2 7 5
6 3 5 6
7 4 6 7
8 4 5 8
```

`x` and `y` represent indices from `datax` and `datay`. `w` represents a score from comparing `datax[x]` with `datay[y]`. I want to maximize the total score (or `w`) from `d`, where each value of `x` is matched to at most one value of `y`, and vice versa.

The result should look like this:

```
  x y w
1 1 6 2
2 2 7 5
3 3 5 6
4 4 5 8
```

Where the sum of all `w` values is maximized, and each `x` and each `y` show up only once in the result.

How do I set up this optimization problem?

Comment: What is $d$? Also in your example $y=5$ shows up twice, is this not allowed?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem

Comment: @eyio, are you the OP from another account? If so, and you have lost control to the other account, you can consider [merging your account](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) to get back ownership of the question.

Answer (score 0):

You must pick $(2,8)\to5$ as this is the only occurrence of 8.

You must pick $(3,5)\to6$ as this is the only occurrence of 3.

You then cannot pick $(2,7)$ so you must pick $(1,7)\to3$ as this is the only remaining occurrence of 7.

You then cannot pick $(1,6)$ so you must pick $(4,6)\to7$ as this is the only remaining occurrence of 6.

So there is no optimization as you have no other options.

So $w=5+6+3+7=21$